# How do I create a dataframe containing only two variables of each set?

Tags: r, dataframe

Here's an example of my data:

```
Environment Car Time (seconds)
Snow         A  128
Snow         B  143
Snow         C  132
Snow         D  114
Snow         E  145
Dirt         A  134
Dirt         B  130
Dirt         C  146
Dirt         D  112
Dirt         E  102
Road         A  107
Road         B  134
Road         C  144
Road         D  125
Road         E  125
```

I want to create a file that will only contain data for Car A and Car C.
Any suggestions how to do it in R?

Comment: that looks like it, but I wanted to create the new data frame containing two  variables (in the case of your suggestion that creates for one cell_type; I wanted to get for two)

Comment: `df[df$Car %in% c("A", "C"),]`

Comment: that works, thanks!

an additional question - how can I sort it to make sure A is first in the list before C?

Comment: Do you mean all A values come before any C values or that A comes before C within the Environment groups (like in your full data)

Comment: A values come before C within the Environment groups.

Comment: `df2 = df[df$Car %in% c("A", "C"),]`    
`df2[order(df2$Environment, df2$Car),]`

Comment: works perfectly, thanks!